# Show that $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}([c,\infty))$ is measurable for every $c\in \mathcal{S}$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued function and $\mathcal{S}$ a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is measurable if and only if $$f^{-1}([c,\infty))$$ is measurable for every $c\in \mathcal{S}$.

*Proof:*

Theorem: A function $:\mathbb{R}\to [-\infty,\infty]$ is measurable if and only if $f^-1(E)\in \mathcal{M}$ for every $E\in\mathcal{B}$.

How would I go with this? I was thinking that we need to show that $[c,\infty)$ is a Borel set. But it seems too familiar to the the proof of the theorem above.

Comment: Hint: the collection $[c, +\infty)$ is a p-system.

Comment: What is a p-system?

Comment: A p-system, or $\pi$-system sometimes is a nonempty collection of subsets of a sample space $\Omega$ which is closed under finite intersections. p-systems function as bases for sigma algebras and they have some good characteristics. This p-system generates the Borel sigma algebra, therefore, your function is measurable (you don't need to examine what happens with all the sets of your sigma algebra, just check the sets of the p-system that generates it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward direction is automatic, so lets look at the reverse direction.

Let $C = \{ [c,\infty) \mid c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ as is mentioned in the hints, $\sigma(C) = \mathcal{B}$ i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets in the question is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. We will use this in the proof, so if you haven't covered this, you may need to prove it.

Using this, consider the collection 
$$\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid f^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{M} \}$$
Now, verify that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Using this, we have
$$ C \subseteq \mathcal {A}$$
(by the assumption of the problem) hence,
$$ \mathcal{B} = \sigma(C) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A}$$
Thus, $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A}$, so $f$ is measurable.

To show $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, you need to show

(i) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$

(ii) $A \in \mathcal{A} \implies A^c \in \mathcal{A}$

(iii) $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots \implies \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{A}$

If you need help showing any of these, I can add to my answer, but they are not hard to show using the properties of inverse image.

**Edit**: Explanations for (ii) and (iii)

(ii) Suppose $A \in \mathcal {A}$.  This means $f^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{M}$.  We want to show that $f^{-1}[A^c] \in \mathcal{M}$

Now,
$$f^{-1}[A^c] = \{x \mid f(x) \in A^c \} = \{ x \mid f(x) \notin A \} = \left ( \{x \mid f(x) \in A \} \right)^c = (f^{-1}[A])^c$$

Since $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (it is closed under complements), and $f^{-1}[A] \in \mathcal{M}$, $f^{-1}[A^c] = (f^{-1}[A])^c \in \mathcal{M}$. So $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$.

(iii) Assume $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$.  Then,
$$f^{-1}[\bigcup_i^\infty A_i] = \{ x \mid f(x) \in A_i \text{ for some $i$ } \} = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{x \mid f(x) \in A_i\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f^{-1}[A_i] $$

Since, $\mathcal{M}$ is closed under countable unions, $f^{-1}[\bigcup_i^\infty A_i] = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f^{-1}[A_i] \in \mathcal{M}$.  So $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Yes please. Can you add the prove of the 3 conditions?

Comment: I'll add (ii) and (iii), try to think about (i): what is $f^{-1}[\emptyset]$?

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to Measure Theory,so please check the solution and notify me

The first implication is obvious.

Conversely given that $\{x:f(x)\ge c\}$ is measurable for each $c\in S$.

Now let $c\in \Bbb R$ then as $S$ is dense there exits an increasing  sequence $c_n\to c$ where $c_n\in S$ .

Then $\{x:f(x)\ge c\}=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)\ge x_n\}$ which is measurable as Measurable sets form a $\sigma$ algebra.